# How can open screen in particular nested list node in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I’ve created a tab panel which has 2 tabs; ***Stock Items*** and ***Favorite***. In ***Stock Items*** I’ve added nested list with following tree structure.

```
Stock Items -> Item1
            -> Item2   -> Item3 -> MyForm
Favorite -> MyForm
```

When user clicked on Item3 then ‘***MyForm***’ screen launched. User can favorite this screen if he/she does not want to travell long path to open MyForm screen so in this way he/she can add this screen in favorite list and after adding this screen in favorite, this screen will visible in Favorite tab section from where user can launch ‘**MyForm**’ screen without travelling long path.

So let me know how can perform this task?.
Any help is appreiciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TouchStyle demo: http://www.sencha.com/apps/touchstyle (you should also have it you samples folder in your ST folder).

Look for `routes` configuration in the main app controller. This is how you can navigate and through the app and remember where you were:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-routes